# Extending a CustomDialog, edittext always empty

Tags: java, android, inheritance, dialog

I am trying to add a custom field to IconDialog (https://github.com/maltaisn/icondialoglib)

I added a new EditText into the xml and I am trying to access it in my activity onIconDialogIconsSelected (which is a Callback when the Select button of this dialog is pressed).

The editText.getText() is always empty but I can see it when debugging in the view.

The new class:

```
public class InputIconDialog extends IconDialog {
    private EditText editText;
    public InputIconDialog() {

    }

    public String getInputText() {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.icd_dialog_icon, null);
        editText = v.findViewById(R.id.icd_edt_InputName); // this editText exists but is always empty
        return editText.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not actually accessing the view on display. You inflated a new `View` on a null parent `ViewGroup` in this line `View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.icd_dialog_icon, null);`. Although view has been created it is not tied to anything UI wise.

The other problem is that in `IconDialog` you already set the content of the dialog to the view `dialog.setContentView(view);` that you inflated there.

---

A simple solution would be to allow the children of `IconDialog` to change its base layout.

```
public class IconDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @LayoutRes
    protected int layoutRes = R.layout.icd_dialog_icon;

    Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle state) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View view = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null);
}

public class InputIconDialog extends IconDialog {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layoutRes = R.layout.icd_dialog_icon;
    }
```

A major drawback to such solution is its maintainability long term in the sense that the children of `IconDialog` need to include all the views it depends on in their layout with `<inclue` or replication.

---

**Recommendation**

> I would use [`onCreateView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#BasicDialog) in `IconDialog` to set the layout and views and then override it in `InputIconDialog` and call super. That plus 3 layout files, one for icon_dialog, one for the shared views between the 2 dialogs and one for input_icon_dialog.

Comment: Thank you for this input.
So, there is no option of achieving this without touching the IconDialog itself? Thats what I wanted to avoid so I keep the maintainability of the app.

Comment: You probably can get the current view (`IconDialog` view) from `InputIconDialog` and alter it but that is hackier.

Another thing you can do which is a little cleaner is to use [`onCreateView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#BasicDialog) in `IconDialog` to set the layout and views and then override it in `InputIconDialog` and call super. That plus 3 layout files, one for icon_dialog, one for the shared views between the 2 dialogs and one for input_icon_dialog. I would go for that approach if I were you

Comment: I ended up updating IconDialog indeed.